# Exposing Data as C# Properties - Good or Bad?

Tags: c#, oop, properties

I am kinda not getting my head around this and was wondering if someone could please help me understand this.

So here is the problem, I have a class in which there are no required parameters. If user does not set the fields I can take the default value and carry on. Previously, I designed the same class as Joshua Bloch's Builder Pattern (Effective Java) (immutable object). I didn't had any good reason for making the class immutable except for the fact that I didn't wanted to have telescopic constructors and I didn't wanted to expose the data of the class.

But now, a fellow programmer friend is trying to convince me that it's okay to expose the data from the class using C# properties. I am not sure about this and I still feel that I should not be allowing user to muck with data.

Maybe I am completely wrong in my understanding. Could someone please clear my doubt about this, that whether it's good or bad to expose the data from the class?

If it is good then in what case it is good? Or else if someone can please point me to the article/book that clarifies this I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx) article by Jon Skeet if you're wondering properties or fields.

Answer (score 4):

Expose the data in the class if it is needed or of interest outside the class, and do not do so if it is not. Expose it read-only if it's only needed to be read outside, and expose it as a full read/write property if it should be able to be changed. Otherwise, keep it in a private field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew. If I do end up exposing the data then would it not be violation of encapsulation? This is where I was getting confused at.

Comment: It's a violation *if* there is no good, architectural reason to expose it. By using properties instead of public fields, you potentially maintain the aspects of encapsulation, too.

Answer (score 2):

immutable classes are easier to reason about especially in a multi tasking application, but they usually pay in performance (because when you need to change the value of a field you need to build the whole class again with the new value).
So, you could be ok or (depending on what you're coding) even better off with properties but as usual there's no silver bullet.

Settable properties are also the only way to code objects for some specific frameworks or libraries (e.g. ORMs like NHibernate), because you can't control how the library/framework initializes the object.

About constructors, C# 4 has [optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx), that could help you avoid a long chain of constructors and also communicate much more clearly the fact that the parameters are optional.

However I can't think of many cases where you would end up with classes with a long list of optional parameters. If you find that you're coding classes like that too often (especially with the builder pattern, which is very elegant looking on the consumers' side of the class but complicates the code for the class itself) you may be using the wrong design. Are you sure you are not asking your classes to have too many responsibilities?

Comment: Wow didn't know about optional parameters in C#. Thanks for that. In my case thou it won't work as class has many fields and all of them are optional except one. :-(

Comment: in case you aren't aware of them, C# also has [object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx) that use settable properties at initialization with a very lightweight syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It basically depend on what's the purpose of your Class in the application context (could you give us more details?). 
Anyway reckon that you could make a property safe from external changes by declaring is setter as private:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

```
public string UserName { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Thanks much for the reply mamoo. The class is a builder class that first creates all the appropriate entries in the data base and then loads it into the class object. And the data to be exposed is for setting some values for these database table entries. Please let me know if more information is required. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's "good" when the consumer of the class needs the data. You have two possibilities to offer properties. 
if you only want to offer a property for information purpose, then choose a read only property like this:

```
public string MyInformation { get; private set; }
```

If you have the need to allow the consumer to change that property, then make the setter public like that:

```
public string MyChangeableInformation { get; set; }
```

But if the consumer has no need to get the information, then hide it in your class!

Answer (score 0):

> But now, a fellow programmer friend is trying to convince me that it's
>   okay to expose the data from the class using C# properties. I am not
>   sure about this and I still feel that I should not be allowing user to
>   muck with data.

As a rule of thumb, methods should represent actions whereas properties represent data. What your friend might have tried telling you is that you can expose the data of your class to outside world and still maintain full control on how other classes are accessing the data. In your case, as other have mentioned, you can use properties with private setters, such that the caller should not be able to modify the data.

Comment: That's the problem. That I do want users to set the data optionally. For ex., if they don't set it I will take the default value. And using immutable class using my previous design was allowing users to set the data only once.

Comment: If you want to have implement immutable functionality, then you will have to use the "readonly" keyword. In this case, you either will have to initialize the value at the time of declaration or in the constructor. And then you can expose those properties via getter properties.